# Wiring my own RJ45 sockets - issues with a paticular outlet not negotiating at 1GB

Tags: networking

I used a tester to test the patch cables I've used. They seem to be fine. I was advised to punchdown keystone jacks on both ends of the cable then use patch cable for the final leg. I've ensured the patch cable are cat5e and router/pc are gigabit ethernet capable.

The same pc syncs at 1gb on a different link connected to the same router.

When I put the tester on, pins 1 and 8 didn't light up on both the master unit and the remote. As far I can see I punched them down as far they can go. Also the keystone on the pc end is toolless so the caps should punch them down for me. Yet only 100mb ethernet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer is re-terminate the cable. I've made up so many cables that looked OK but failed on speed or continuity checks that I don't question the tester results any more.

Comment: Can I just check am not being an idiot. I have to admint am a DIY'er and by no means a professional. I can use these on solid core cable right? http://www.screwfix.com/p/philex-rj45-cat5e-jack-punch-down-outlet-90-white/72694

Comment: Follow this answer.  His point is EXCELLENT and will save you time.

Comment: As for solid core???  Surely don't mean COAX??  The type of cable this type of jack is for would NOT be solid core (at least I've never heard it referred to that way) it's twisted pair.  Solid Core "sounds" like COAX or some other similar type.

Comment: http://www.dcdi.co.uk/product/302/network-cables/89/cat5e-stranded-utp/831/cat5e-stranded-utp-cable?gclid=CNekjPrSmK0CFYuIfAod8UKRng  is that not inivididual fine strands of wire twisted together? It's more flexible so they use this for patch cable. The cat5e cable with solid conductor i.e. solid core to electronics ppl. Am not correct? I used cat5e with solid cooper conductor for the the keystone jacks

Comment: This is definitely the correct kind of cable but I have never heard the solid core description before.  Perhaps I just learned something :)  Aside from that though yes you have the right stuff.  The cable is composed of 4 pairs of cables twisted together in either a shielded or unshielded sheath.

Comment: @ageis23 You are correct in your thinking. You use solid-core for punch downs (wires in walls don't move), and in most cases you use stranded for patches between sockets/devices (because they can flex if the device is moved a bunch).  Punch-downs, and RJ-45 end crimps (on patch cables) often need to be done a couple times to get them right (more times than not in my experience).  For the record, the stranded cable you linked is NOT what you want to use in the keystone jacks you linked.  :)